# How to run Drupal console command from code?

Tags: 8, console

I have found a lot of documentation on how to run Drush commands from code, but I'm specifically looking on how to run a [Drupal Console](https://hechoendrupal.gitbooks.io/drupal-console/content/en/index.html) command from code.

I have some experience in Symfony and I know how to run a Symfony command from code. Since a Drupal console command extends on Symfony command, I thought this should be rather easy. Simply following [this tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/console/command_in_controller.html) doesn't amount to anything though.

I am trying to run a command in a `hook_cron()` implementation in a custom module.

Comment: Please elaborate why you would downvote my question. I've spend close to an hour in the code and over an hour on the internet for a solution, but I just can't get there.

Comment: What if you use the php functions exec() or shell_exec() ? I haven't done it before but it's the first thing I would try.

Comment: It's weird how you can become so fixated on doing it 1 way that forget about the other, way easier ways.. Will accept as answer if you add it ;)

Comment: Thanks. I've added the answer with refernces to the php docs to help others as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the PHP functions [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) or [shell_exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php).

Comment: But do so carefully and responsibly.

Answer (score 8):

Run shell commands via the `Process` class available in the Symfony framework.

[From the Symfony docs:](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html)

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;

$process = new Process('ls -lsa');
$process->run();

// executes after the command finishes
if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
}

echo $process->getOutput();
```

> The component takes care of the subtle differences between the
>   different platforms when executing the command.

Replace the `ls -lsa` command in the `Process()` constructor with your Drupal console command.

Comment: This is more in the way I was looking for indeed. Sticking with `exec` for now since there aren't any parameters and the command is fixed, but this is nice for better handling of your commands.

Comment: Thank you, this approach looks good. There is a function `drush_shell_exec_interactive` which shows more imformation for interactive commands, like `drush cim -y`. But it is deprecated. I am still looking for a replacement for this function.

Answer (score 0):

In D10 at least you can now run e.g.:

```
  $modules = ['redis'];
  \Drupal::service('module_installer')->install($modules, TRUE);
```

So many things you would want to do with Drush now can be called directly through Drupal services.