# How to display command output programatically Drupal 8

Tags: 8

Based on the input from [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/239501/how-to-run-drupal-console-command-from-code#239531) I am running a command. Basically I need to run [phpmetrics](https://github.com/phpmetrics/PhpMetrics) from backend, so administrator(or user has access) can run the latest custom module dependency status.

I created a config form, and on "submitForm" I an running the command with:

```
$process->run()
```

I need help to diaply the output of the command:

```
php ../vendor/bin/phpmetrics.phar --report-html=sites/default/files/metrics-report ./modules
```

It shows in console as:

```
Lines of code                               115
    Logical lines of code                       67
    Comment lines of code                       48....
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! You've not explicitly asked a question, so far you've only stated a problem. It will be hard for anyone to answer a question with out knowing what it is.

Comment: @ShawnConn I understood, and I am trying to explain by editing the question with more details